# Permutations of length $13$, decomposition into cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Can we decompose all elements of the permutation group $S_{13}$ into cycles of length $5$?

We've just learned decompositions into cycles and I am still trying to comprehend. I know that any element in $S_k$ can be decomposed into disjoint cycles. But, how does the length take play here?

Comment: $(12)$ is an odd permutation. It cannot equal a product of cycles of length $5$, which is an even permutation.

Comment: I agree that $(12)$ is an odd permutation. I do not understand why the product of cycles of length $5$ is an even permutation?

Comment: By cycle of length $5$, do you mean $5$-cycle? Like $(12345)$?

Comment: Yes, $5$ cycles like $(12345)$

Comment: Then $5$-cycles are even permutations. Their product is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework, here are a few questions you should ask yourself that could help you go further:
(the kind of questions Polya outlined in his famous "how to solve it)

1. Can I first find a restricted case I could understand in detail ?

   - What are the permutations that are decomposed into only one cycle ?
   - In that case, is there a link between the length of the cycle and the properties of the permutation ?
   - How is that link evolving when I add one or more cycles ?
   - Can I work a few simple and short examples on paper to sort it out ?
2. What is specific in the question asked ?

   - Is 13 relevant ?
   - Is the couple (13 ; 5) relevant ?
3. What are the constraints I know between a symmetric group and the permutations it contains, more generally between a finite group and its permutations ?

   - Have I learnt theorems and results on this ?
   - Can I cross this with theme no 2 ?